# BrowserRouter is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Whenever I run my code I am getting the following errors on my web application:

> Error: `useHref(`) may be used only in the context of a `<Router>` component.

> Error: [BrowserRouter] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

I am using "react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0".

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component";
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
          <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />  
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an inbuild function `Route` in `react-router-dom`. So It is telling that you cannot call `BrowserRouter` as `Route`. You just need to do like below,

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component";
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
            <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
            <Route path="/create"  component={CreateExercise} />
            <Route path="/user"   component={CreateUser} />  
          </Routes>
    <Router>
  </div>
);
}
export default App;
```

If you need a very good idea on `react-router-dom` configuration. Read  https://medium.com/@sujith1396/a-basic-implementation-on-react-router-dom-v6-e9ff3b4e0529

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BrowserRouter` wrong.
Inside of `BrowserRouter` component you can put your "static" components (as per Sujith Sandeep's answer):

```
<Router>
    <Navbar /> // this is a static component, it is shown always
    ...
</Router>
```

And then put `Routes` component inside of the same `BrowserRouter`, children of which are "swapped" based on your browsers URL:

```
<Routes> // this component renders only one of its children based on URL
    <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
    <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
    <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
    <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
</Routes>
```

So ultimately what you missed was `BrowserRouter` component which handles all the components swaps.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You've imported the `BrowserRouter` as a `Route` and likely have no router component wrapping the `App`/UI and providing a routing context. The `Route` component API also changed, gone are the `component` and `render`  and `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

## Solution

Import the `BrowserRouter` correctly and render the components into it. Render the routed components on the `Route` component's `element` prop as JSX.

Example:

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<ExercisesList />} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditExercise />} />
          <Route path="/create" element={<CreateExercise />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />  
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```